# SQL Syntax Error after upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upgrade

I'm in the process of moving a site/database to a new server and upgrading and am receiving the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND MONTH(`DateCaught`) = ORDER BY `DateCaught`,`Name` ASC' at line 1

The code in question is:

```
if ($selmonth == "0"):
    $query_rsReports = "SELECT `DateCaught` , `Name` , `Boat` , cr.`Species` , `Weightlb` , `Weightoz` , `lb`, `oz`";
    $query_rsReports .= "FROM `CatchReport` cr, `SpecimenWeight` sw ";
    $query_rsReports .= "WHERE sw.species = cr.species AND  YEAR(`DateCaught`)=$selyear ORDER BY `DateCaught`,`Name` ASC";
else:
    $query_rsReports = "SELECT `DateCaught` , `Name` , `Boat` , cr.`Species` , `Weightlb` , `Weightoz` , `lb`, `oz`";
    $query_rsReports .= "FROM `CatchReport` cr, `SpecimenWeight` sw ";
    $query_rsReports .= "WHERE sw.`Species` = cr.`Species` AND  YEAR(`DateCaught`)=$selyear AND MONTH(`DateCaught`)=$selmonth ORDER BY `DateCaught`,`Name` ASC"; 
endif;
```

Any suggestions as to what the problem is would be much appreciated - I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing but can't spot it!

Comment: My guess is the new server has error reporting turned on when the old one did not

Comment: Missing substitution for $selmonth

Comment: This will happen if `$selmonth` has no value in this statement `MONTH(`DateCaught`)=$selmonth` So why all of a sudden does `$selmonth` have no value

Comment: check value in `$selyear`, if it's blank then it will throw above error, and I guess both variables are blank

Comment: Another thing to check is that if $selmonth == "0" or empty($selmonth)

Comment: Thank you for the replies - appreciate it. $selyear is simply where the user selects a year from a dropdown box, likewise $selmonth. When they pick a month/year, the script displays the results from that month as text.

It is working on the old server here: http://www.pbsbac.co.uk/showcatchreport2.php

and not on the new one here: http://pbsbac.vanderquest.co.uk/catchreport/showcatchreport2.php